# Kivy and Kivmob: Reference Error- Weekly reference error no longer exists

Tags: python, android, error-handling, reference, kivy

I recently made a app in kivy and wanted to deploy it on my phone using buildozer. Everything works fine unless I use kivmob. Kivmob is a module for integrating ads with admob on kivy. But I have seen my ads multiple times. Today when I ran my programm I got the error in the logcat which says -Reference Error - weekly referenced object no longer exits.The important thing to mention is that the app worked fine for one day. I am sure that it is not the problem of kivmob.. It is the problem of my code. What is this error and how could I fix it.

```
# I think under on_start method something is wrong
class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return GUI

    def change_screen(self,screen_name):
        # get the screen manager from the kv file
        screen_manager = self.root.ids['screen_manager']
        screen_manager.current = screen_name
        # screen_manager = self.root.ids

    def on_start(self):
        self.ads = KivMob("ca-app-pub-***************")
        self.ads.new_interstitial("ca-app-pub-*************")
        self.ads.add_test_device("***********")
        self.ads.request_interstitial()
        self.ads.new_banner("ca-app-pub-************",top_pos=False)
        self.ads.request_banner()
        self.ads.show_banner()
        from kivy.base import EventLoop
        EventLoop.window.bind(on_keyboard = self.hook_keyboard)

    def hook_keyboard(self,window,key,*largs):
        if key == 27:
            # write whatever u want
            self.change_screen("home_screen")
            return True
    def on_resume(self):
        self.ads.request_interstitial()
```

```
#In my kv file I call the interstitial function. So when user presses play button the ad will appear. It worked fine for one day
ImageButton:
    source: "icon/play.png"
    on_release:
        app.change_screen("topics_screen")
        app.ads.show_interstitial()
```

[This is the error I am getting. Click me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dImeT.png)
   or click this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dImeT.png

Comment: To let people help you, perhaps it is better to post the actual error and not what part of it you think is important.. ;o)

Comment: I have edited the post and posted an Imgae of the error